# Table borders overlap hover content

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, html-table

I'm having an issue where table borders overlap my tooltips, but only in the most recent version of chrome (Version 91.0.4472.77 (Official Build) (arm64)). As an example:

[image: Hover overlap by browser]

Code is in [this notebook](https://observablehq.com/@mkfreeman/overlapping-border-issue).

Answer (score 0):

The SVG needed to be wrapped in a div:

${Histogram(data, "bill_depth")}
  
  
    ${Histogram(data, "bill_length")}